# Kernel Logging stopped

Tags: 11.04, kernel, logging

I found the following line at the end of my `/var/log/messages.1`

```
Apr 29 13:58:29 MyLaptop kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

`/var/log/messages` is indeed empty? This happened when I updated to Natty. I am trying to debug another problem so I am wondering: what happened? Where did my logging go to?

How can I turn it back on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like kernel logging will be output to `/var/log/kern.log` in Natty. The line you're seeing (Kernel logging stopped) will have been the last entry before the output was switched to the new file.

This is all configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`, if you're keen to poke around.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was not sure it was correct because I am missing some log entries but that is a totally different problem I guess.